# Converting Text to ProperCase in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm

I'm creating a wpf control with the odd text box on it for which I wish the text to be converted to Proper Case.

To that end I have created a converter;

```
Public Class TextToPropperCaseConverter
Implements IValueConverter


Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim txt As String = TryCast(parameter, String)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) Then
        Return StrConv(txt, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
    Else
        Return txt.ToString
    End If
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return Nothing
End Function
End Class
```

and then gone on to reference in on the relevant text box in my xaml like so;

```
 <wizard:AeroWizardWindow.Resources>
    <local:TextToPropperCaseConverter x:Key="txtToPcase"/>
</wizard:AeroWizardWindow.Resources>

<TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="8,8,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Address, Converter={StaticResource txtToPcase}}" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="232"/>
```

Perhaps somewhat naively I was expected the text entered in the text box to change either as the user typed or better as the control lost focus, but nothing happened.

Is this the correct way to be doing this, or is this perhaps, despite the fact that I'm using MVVM and trying to avoid code behind, a classic example of where code behind would actually be better?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement the conversion from user input to a `ViewModel` property you need to implement `ConvertBack`. See also the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. You return `Nothing`, this means that no matter what you type in the `TextBox`, `Nothing` will always be the resulting value from using the converter.

Comment: Ah, thank you that makes sense.  Would that mean that in essence the code in the convert back would be pretty much identical to the code in convert?

Comment: @DomSinclair Judging from your question, you want to convert the input text to `ProperCase`. If so, the `Convert` implementation also works for `ConvertBack`.